# Browser gzip decompression overhead / speed

Tags: performance, browser, compression, gzip

What is the browser's overhead to decompress a gzip server response of an average sized web page?

<1ms 1-3ms? more?

Comment: Say around 1.3M or so. It doesn't need to be exact.  I just want to know what sort of overhead exists during the unzip process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume that you mean 1.3M uncompressed.  I get about 6 ms decompression time on one core of a 2 GHz i7.

If I assume 1/3 compression, an extra 7 Mbits needs to be transferred if not compressed.  That will take more than 6 ms on a 1 Gbit/s link.  700 ms on a more typical 10 Mbit/s link.

gzip is a big win for HTTP transfers.

Comment: 7,270,127 bits transferred at 100Mbps would take 8.6ms.  So the browser overhead is 6ms and the server overhead to do the gzip is 2ms, it is it a wash?

Comment: No still worth it. The communication link is a shared resource, and sending an extra 7M bits over this is affecting all users on the wire, so you want to keep off this if you can (CSMA/CD).

Comment: This is new territory for me. Just about everything I read says gzip is a win/win, a few people talk about first byte to browser and that it's not so good.  I have a very limited understanding of networks so I tried using this calculator: http://www.calctool.org/CALC/prof/computing/transfer_time  Thank you for helping me sort through this...

Comment: If implemented properly, decompression will introduce almost no latency.  You only have to get through about 80 bytes of the compressed data before it starts delivering uncompressed data.

Comment: I don't know if you understood my arithmetic comment.  Your calculation of the 8.6 ms is off by about a factor of ten.  It should be about 70 ms.

Comment: I see now, 7 Mbit transferred at 100Mbps = 66ms   I was using 100MBps to arrive at 8ms.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, @MarkAdler your general comment on decompression latency could very well be part of the answer, and perhaps elaborated.

Comment: @Brian McGinity, if you're still reading, I think it's important to note that almost no one has a 100 Mbps connection. On mobile we're sometimes lucky to have 2 Mbps.

Answer (score 3):

Using zlib implementation of gzip with default parameters.

On an internet facing server, Xeon cpu 2.66Ghz quad core, the gzip compression times are 
Less than 0.5mS up to 15Kb. 361Kb is 4.50mS and 1077Kb takes 13mS

I consider this still easily worth it however, as most of our traffic is heading out over wifi or 3G links, so transfer time far outweighs server delay.

The times are measured with code bracketing only the call to gzip routines and use nS precision timers, I changed the source to implement this. I was measuring this anyway, as I was trying to determine if caching gzip was worth the memory tradeoff, or was gzip fast enough anyway. In our case, I think we will gzip everything above about 200bytes, and aggresively cache gzip'd responses, especially for larger packets.

(@Mark adler, thanks for writing zlib)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings. How are you measuring this?  I am not sold that enabling gzip on the web server is improving the user experience because the network is so fast with 20ms ping times.

Comment: It's not about ping time.  It's about transfer time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, which was about decompression.